# how to change variable through interface inheritance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want each projectile in my game to contain a bool saying if its the player's or not

```
public interface projectile
{
    public bool isPlayers { get; set; }
}

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour, projectile
{
    public bool isPlayers { get { return (_isPlayers); } set { _isPlayers = value; } }
    private bool _isPlayers;
}
```

when any weapon fires i check if it was by the player or not and set it accordingly

```
public class Cannon : MonoBehaviour, Iaweapon
{ 
    ...
    public void Attack()
    {
        ...
            if(transform.parent.tag == "Player")
            {
                prefab.GetComponent<projectile>().isPlayers = true;
            }
        ...
    }
}
```

but when debugging the bool is not set to true

Comment: It's likely that the code you've provided isn't the actual code you're working with. For example, the interface has the 'public' access modifier which is something you wouldn't add in an interface. If you added your actual code, we might have a better chance at spotting the issue.

Your code also mentioned looking at a prefabs 'projectile' component. I dare say you should be looking at an instance of a 'projectile' (Bullet), not the prefab. But this might be an issue with your naming convention. Again, without more of the actual code, it's hard to determine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the varialbe names, I'm going to assume that you're checking a 'prefab' instead of an instantiated object. With that in mind, your code should look something more like this:

```csharp
public interface IProjectile
{
    bool isPlayers { get; set; }
}


public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour, IProjectile
{
    ...
    public bool isPlayers { get; set; }
}


public class Cannon : MonoBehaviour, IWeapon
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject prefab;
    ...
    public void Attack()
    {
        ...
        var instance = Instantiate ( prefab );
        var component = instance.GetComponent<IProjectile>( );
        if ( component != null )
            component.isPlayers = transform.parent.CompareTag( "Player" );
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class does not implement your interface.

In order to do it you will have to add it as you did for *Iaweapon* interface.

```
 public class Cannon : MonoBehaviour, Iaweapon,  projectile
{ 
    ...
    public void Attack()
    {
```

Also in order for you to be able to recognise easier your different types such as interfaces I recommend you putting an "I" before all of you your interface names. It will make your life easier.

Comment: Why does `Cannon` need to implement `projectile`?

Comment: If you want to have it inside the Cannon then you can try initializing an object of type Bullet inside the Cannon class and then set it via this object to true.                            etc Bullet bul = new Bullet(); bul.isPlayers = true;

Comment: does not seem to fix the problem

Comment: During your debug, are you able to get inside of  if(transform.parent.tag == "Player") block?

Comment: yes and debug.log(isplayers) returns true but in the bullet instance it returns false

Comment: Could you provide some more code information along with the case that I gave you? I mean by initializing the Bullet object within the Attack method